# C# - Select and Count the Selected Row in FlexGrid

Tags: c#, winforms

How to count and select the selected row using c# with flexGrid in Windows Form App.

for example in 7 data in row i want to select 3 row only and will display the value of 3 row..

```
for(int i = e.Row; i < e.Row; i++){
  string _c = grid.GetData(e.Row, "isSelected").ToString();
  MessageBox.Show(_c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, it seems that you want to get all the row data out and show it in a message box. If this is the case, then:

According to [this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/webframe.html#rowsandcolumns.html), in c# the way you get the columns count is
**grid.Cols.Count**

And [this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGridBase~GetData.html) states that we get the data out using
**grid.GetData(row,col)**

So knowing that, we could make a method which would iterate through the colums to get the data out:

```
private string GetRowData(int row){  
    string _c;
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.Cols.Count; ++i){
         _c += (grid.GetData(row, i));
    }
    return _c;
}
```

Then if you want to display each of the rows in a message box (as you did in you question), you could do:

```
for(int i = e.Row; i < e.Row; i++){
    MessageBox.Show(GetRowData(e.Row));
}
```

I haven't tested this out, but seems like it should work.